# How to filter multiple columns in an HTML table?

Tags: javascript

I want to implement a filtering function similar to the one in excel, however I want two options "All" and "None", "None" hides all rows if a certain column has empty/blank cells and "All" hides all rows if a certain column has non-empty/non-blank cells. It is just like the excel filter functionality but a bit more generalized.

How can I implement this?

my first approach was to simply see if the cell is empty or not and based on the selection i would either hide it or not, that did not work as removing filters would affect different unrelated columns.

my second approach was to have a huge hashmap of arrays with values "All", "None". each column had its own array in the hashmap. "All" and "None" would be removed/added based on if they are checked\unchecked in that column. then it checks if either "All" or "None" are unchecked and if the cells is not blank or blank respectively for every row and every column

this is a jsfiddle to showcase what my code looks like
https://jsfiddle.net/7ng4adfh/

This is my code

```
function filter_rows(index, parentID) {
    let rows = tableid.rows;
    let options = document.getElementById(parentID).getElementsByTagName('label')
    let checkboxes = document.getElementById(parentID).getElementsByTagName('input')
    for (let i = 0; i < options.length; i++) {
        if (checkboxes[i].checked) {
            if (!hashmapOfoptions[index].includes(options[i].innerText)) {
                hashmapOfoptions[index].push(options[i].innerText)
            }
        } else {
            hashmapOfoptions[index] = hashmapOfoptions[index].filter(item => item !== options[i].innerText)
        }
    }


    for (let row = 1; row < rows.length; row++) {
        let cols = rows[row].cells;
        willHideRow = false
        for (let j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
            if (!hashmapOfoptions[j].includes("None")) {
                if (cols[j].innerText == "" || cols[j].innerText == "-" || cols[j].innerText == "\n") {
                    willHideRow = true
                }
            }
            if (!hashmapOfoptions[j].includes("All")) {
                if (cols[j].innerText != "" || cols[j].innerText != "-" || cols[j].innerText != "\n") {
                    willHideRow = true
                }
            }
        }
        if (willHideRow) {
            rows[row].style.display = 'none'
        } else {
            rows[row].style.display = ''
        }
    }
}
```

How can i make it work?

Comment: I see errors in the console (in your fiddle): I would first make sure you don't have such errors.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple approach would be for each row, for each column check the filter status and enough if one of the filter "fails" then hide the row.

Three comments:

1. You had issues with the logical condition you've used `||` instead of `&&` where needed.
2. I've used directly the values from the DOM.
3. It doesn't make sense to check both "All" and "None" so if this is the case then I ignore the filter.

```js
function filter_rows() {
  // always filter all rows and all columns
  var rows = [...document.querySelectorAll("#tableid tbody>tr")]
  var ths = [...document.querySelectorAll("#tableid thead th")]

  for (let i = 0; i < rows.length; i++) {
    var row = rows[i]
    let cols = [...row.querySelectorAll("td")]
    willHideRow = false
    
    for (let j = 0; j < cols.length; j++) {
      var th = ths[j]
      var chkNone = th.querySelector("[data-filter=None]").checked
      var chkAll = th.querySelector("[data-filter=All]").checked

      // to avoid paradox
      if (chkNone && chkAll || !chkNone && !chkAll) {
        continue;
      }

      if (chkAll) {
        if (cols[j].innerText == "" || cols[j].innerText == "-" || cols[j].innerText == "\n") {
          willHideRow = true
          break
        }
      }
      if (chkNone) {
        if (cols[j].innerText != "" && cols[j].innerText != "-" && cols[j].innerText != "\n") {
          willHideRow = true
          break
        }
      }
    }
    
    if (willHideRow) {
      row.style.display = 'none'
    } else {
      row.style.display = ''
    }
  }

}






table = document.getElementById('tableid')
hashmapOfoptions = {}

function getUniqueValuesFromColumn() {

  let unique_col_values_dict = {}
  let header = table.rows[0].cells
  let rows = table.rows;
  for (let i = 0; i < header.length; i++) {
    unique_col_values_dict[i] = new Array("All")
    unique_col_values_dict[i].push("None")


    header[i].innerHTML += `<form><div class="multiselect"><div class="selectBox" onclick="showCheckboxes('checkbox${i}')"><select><option></option></select><div class="overSelect"></div></div><div class = "checkboxes" id="checkbox${i}"></div></div></form>`
    options = ""
    for (let j = 0; j < unique_col_values_dict[i].length; j++) {
      options += `<label><input type="checkbox" data-filter="${unique_col_values_dict[i][j]}" checked = "true" onchange="filter_rows(${i},'checkbox${i}')" />${unique_col_values_dict[i][j]}</label>`
    }
    document.getElementById(`checkbox${i}`).innerHTML = options
  }

}

let expanded = false;

function showCheckboxes(elementID) {
  let checkboxes = document.getElementById(elementID);
  if (!expanded) {
    checkboxes.style.display = "block";
    expanded = true;
  } else {
    checkboxes.style.display = "none";
    expanded = false;
  }
}

getUniqueValuesFromColumn()
```

```css
* {
  margin: 0px;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: Arial, Helvetica, sans-serif;
}

.heading {
  display: flex;
  background-color: #232f3e;
  box-shadow: 0px 1px 2px #232f3e;
}

h1 {
  color: coral;
  font-weight: bold;
  background: transparent;
  padding: 7px;
}

.outer-wrapper {
  margin-top: 40px;
  margin-left: 20px;
  margin-right: 20px;
  border: 1px solid black;
  border-radius: 4px;
  box-shadow: 0px 0px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.9);
  max-width: fit-content;
  max-height: fit-content;
}

.table-wrapper {
  overflow-y: scroll;
  overflow-x: scroll;
  height: fit-content;
  max-height: 66.4vh;
  margin-top: 22px;
  margin: 15px;
  padding-bottom: 20px;
}

table {
  min-width: max-content;
  border-collapse: separate;
  border-spacing: 0px;
}

.table-filter {
  border-radius: 5px;
}

table th {
  position: sticky;
  top: 0px;
  background-color: #133b5c;
  color: rgb(241, 245, 179);
  text-align: center;
  font-weight: normal;
  font-size: 18px;
  outline: 0.7px solid black;
  border: 1.5px solid black;
}

table th,
table td {
  padding: 15px;
  padding-top: 10px;
  padding-bottom: 10px;
}

table td {
  text-align: left;
  font-size: 15px;
  border: 1px solid rgb(177, 177, 177);
  padding-left: 20px;
}

.multiselect {
  width: 100%;
}

.selectBox {
  position: relative;
}

.selectBox select {
  width: 100%;
  font-weight: bold;
}

.overSelect {
  position: absolute;
  left: 0;
  right: 0;
  top: 0;
  bottom: 0;
}

.checkboxes {
  display: none;
  border: 1px #dadada solid;
}

.checkboxes label {
  display: block;
}

.checkboxes label:hover {
  background-color: #1e90ff;
}
```

```html
<table id="tableid">
  <thead>
    <tr>
      <th col-index=1>Employee ID</th>
      <th col-index=2>Gender
      </th>

      <th col-index=3>Department

      </th>
      <th col-index=4>Status
      </th>
      <th col-index=5>Office

      </th>
    </tr>
  </thead>
  <tbody>
    <tr>
      <td>101</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>RnD</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>102</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>RnD</td>
      <td>On Leave</td>
      <td>Site 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>103</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>RnD</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>104</td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 1</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>201</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>On Leave</td>
      <td>Site 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>202</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td><br></td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>203</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>Engineering</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>204</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>Design</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 2</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>301</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>Support</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>302</td>
      <td>F</td>
      <td>Support</td>
      <td>Online</td>
      <td>Site 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>303</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>Terminated</td>
      <td>Site 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>304</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>On Leave</td>
      <td>Site 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>307</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td></td>
      <td>On Leave</td>
      <td>Site 3</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>404</td>
      <td>M</td>
      <td>-</td>
      <td>On Leave</td>
      <td>Site 3</td>
    </tr>


  </tbody>
</table>
```

Comment: can you explain why using values from the dom is not best practice?

Comment: i didn't say that and it depends :-) generally speaking it's the mixing between presentation layer and the data that might make maintainability a bit harder.

Comment: for example, consider a case of sorting values.  you may have dates which when rendered become a string and sorting is different if they were true abstract dates.

Comment: Thank you so much for you help, I just got a two more questions, I noticed you removed the input parameters in the `filter_rows()` function yet in the `getUniqueValuesFromColumn()` function while making the checkboxes you still pass in 2 parameters? how does that work? 
another thing I noticed is lets say  I don't want a filter on "Gender" so i add a conditional in `getUniqueValuesFromColumn()` to skip that column, however when i did that i got this kind of error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of null (reading 'checked')` any idea why?

Comment: i removed the parameters since we always check all columns. as for skipping a column, just don't have the checkboxes there and add condition that if no checkboxes exists, skip the check (do a `continue` before you get this error)